# C#: How to Use a dictionary for a simple inventory app

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am a beginner with Programming and C#. I would like to make a sort of inventory application for fun. (I must be a boring guy) I am using a dictionary to hold my values. My layout on the form is using a textbox for the input of a "bar code" (just something I made up 110011"), a listbox to show what was entered by a proper name with price ("name - price"), and a label to show the total price of everything scanned. Sorta like a store i guess. I have tried using Split and Sum but not getting anything in return. the lable still shows 0.00, the listbox only shows 110011 and the textbox.. I guess actually dose what it should. When I run the code there are no errors so it is running as it should. Here is my code so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace smart_cart
{
    public partial class List : Form
    {
        private object itemlist;
        private object sum;

        public object Next { get; private set; }
        public object ListBox1 { get; private set; }

        public List()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void label1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Text = sum.ToString();
        }

        private void textBox1_KeyPress_1(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyChar == 13)
                this.textBox1.AppendText((sender as ComboBox).Text);
            e.Handled = true;
            {

            }

        }

        private void listBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            }

        private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Enter)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(textBox1.Text);
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Remove(listBox1.SelectedItem);
            }

        private void List_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> Itemlist = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            Itemlist.Add("Bread - 1.49", "110011");
            Itemlist.Add("Shampoo - 4.99", "110022");
            Itemlist.Add("TV - 200.00", "110033");

        }

        private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var sum = listBox1.Items
         .OfType<string>()
         .Select(s => Convert.ToInt32(s.Split(new string[] { "-" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[1]))
         .Sum();
        }
    }
    }
```

Thanks for any help and suggestions. I will keep searching for an answer while I wait for a replay.

Comment: You have `Itemlist` dictionary but you are not using it anywhere. You should create a class to represent a product with properties like Barcode, Name, Price etc. And then create a `Dictionary<string, Product>` where you will have Barcode as key and product object value. You don't need to do string split etc if you go this way.

Answer (score 1):

Since OP is a beginner, he might be unfamiliar with OOP concepts so in-order to make your simple project work with a dictionary all you need to do is declare `Dictionary<string, string> Itemlist = new Dictionary<string, string>();` outside `List_Load` so that the variable scope will cover the entire `List` class.

ex:

```
Dictionary<string, string> Itemlist = new Dictionary<string, string>();

private void List_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    Itemlist.Add("110011", "Bread - 1.49");
    Itemlist.Add("110022", "Shampoo - 4.99");
    Itemlist.Add("110033", "TV - 200.00");
}
```

As you can see above I interchanged the position of your parameters to `Add` since it accepts a key then value. I would prefer to have "110011" as my key instead of "Bread - 1.49".

Now anywhere in your application if you want to get the value from the dictionary you can simply use the following:

```
if (Itemlist.ContainsKey(key))
{
    string value = Itemlist[key];

    string[] split = value.Split('-');

    string label = split[0].Trim();
    double price = double.Parse(split[1]);

    // do something
}
else
{
    // do something?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It occurs because you have defined `sum` variable in your `listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged_1` method locally which hides the global `sum` variable. just remove `var` keyword and it works. Your method should look like:

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    sum = listBox1.Items
          .OfType<string>()
          .Select(s => Convert.ToInt32(s.Split(new string[] { "-" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[1]))
          .Sum();
}
```

Comment: I removed var and tried the code but no change. When I click an item in the list to remove it I get the following error:  

'my_program.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: my_program.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
Exception thrown: 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' in my_program.exe
An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in my_program.exe
Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Answer (score 0):

I think in your case the event is getting triggered

I tried this and it worked .

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(tb_KeyDown);
    }

    static void tb_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
           MessageBox.Show(" some junk");
        }
    }
```